# Why the submit button doesn't show the text?

Tags: html, web-applications

Why the submit button doesn't show the text?

It shows:

[image]

The tag for it: `<input type=submit name="OK"  value=""/>`

Thought `<input type=submit name=OK  value=""/>` would help,but not.

Comment: It's the value that shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value attribute will be shown in the button.

```html
<input type=submit name=OK  value="button"/>
```

Comment: @student It does. If you add `value="foo"` to a text input field, it will initially contain (and display) `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define into `value=""` the text to display.

Example :

```html
<input type=submit name="OK" value="OK" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="submit" name="OK" value="Submit Label"/>
```

See:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp